# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS for Amazon ELB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm using Django and I have the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting to include my `EC2`'s private IP as per below:

```
import requests
EC2_PRIVATE_IP = None
try:
    EC2_PRIVATE_IP = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', timeout=0.01).text
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    pass
if EC2_PRIVATE_IP and not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_PRIVATE_IP)
```

Problem is that the above does not take into consideration the `ELB`'s that forward the request to my `EC2` instances. Is there a way to make that work programmatically? Can I request the public IP address or have setting to check the DNS instead?

I'm seeing this issue with the ELB's public IP address.

Comment: I think it should be your domain name, not your IP. I have EBS and I have this `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.elasticbeanstalk.com', 'mydaomain.com']`. Also make sure you open all the ports in your security groups and add listeners in your load balancer.

Comment: I have `['.compute-1.amazonaws.com', '.elb.amazonaws.com', '.mydaomain.com']` but I get the email for 54.xxx.xxx.xxx all from Amazon. When I put the IP Address in browser it goes to my homepage. So clearly this is something to do with AWS. Could it be Route53 by any chance?

Comment: You can assign elastic IP but there is no need for that. Your domain name DNS should be pointing to the load balancer DNS

Comment: That's really weird. Now I don't know where these emails are coming from.

Comment: Your VPC, Load Balancer and security groups are controlling the access flow. Technically, it should not matter what IP address they have assigned to you. Ont he other hand, some of them are quite "dirty" and were used by spammers.

Comment: Intersting. So you're saying that spammers can be trying to send me requests?

Comment: They may not be targeting you directly. Over the years on AWS I had many IPs that were previously abused and my sites were getting a lot spam, attacks etc. Cloudflare helped me quite a bit with those issues.

Comment: Interesting. I was noticing that these IP's were from Amazon but my website was working properly even without them so I was confused. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another simple solution would be to write a custom `MIDDLEWARE` which will give the response to ELB before the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is checked. So now you don't have to load `ALLOWED_HOSTS` dynamically.

The middleware can be as simple as:

`project/app/middleware.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class HealthCheckMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META["PATH_INFO"] == "/ping/":
            return HttpResponse("pong")
```

`settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Django Middleware reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2023, the health check request now is just to the index path /, not /ping/. My app didn't have an index path so Copilot/ECS kept failing the health check with no explanation and it took me wayyyy too long to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Fetching AWS internal IPs and adding to the ALLOWED_HOST is not the best solution. Since this Fetching will happen only on application reload. ELB IPs can change anytime.

Instead of this, We can set actual host header in the nginx, if this the request is coming from an IP.

Credit goes to: 
https://www.xormedia.com/django-allowed-hosts-and-amazon-elastic-load-balancer/

Comment: Interesting idea! But doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?