# Deploying Django application in AWS. Raise Disallowed Host exception

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ebcli

I am newbie in Amazon Web Services and I'm trying to deploy a Django application using elastic BeansTalk. I'm following the AWS developer guide and when I deploy the application using EBCLI and open the browser to see my application running, I get the following error.

> ```
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/
> ```
>
> Django Version: 1.9.12 Python Version: 3.4.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed
>   Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  123.                 response = middleware_method(request)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  56.         host = request.get_host()

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in get_host
  109.             raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com'. You may need to add 'django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Obviosly the application was deployed but for some reason the exception raises.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667519/why-is-django-throwing-error-disallowedhost-at

Answer (score 11):

You are privileged to get such a verbose error..

> Exception Type: DisallowedHost at / Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST
>   header: 'django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com'. **You
>   may need to add 'django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com'
>   to ALLOWED_HOSTS.**

Just add `django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`

Do something like this

```
#in settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ 'django-env.vsvztq2hxp.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com', ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

in your settings.py file

Here is a great checklist before you deploy in prod. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: adding `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]` is super insecure... It can mean that anyone who does a MIM attack with your code can legitimately run as you. I would NOT do this.