# Django disallowed host error

Tags: python, django

This is the error I get when I visit 127.0.0.1:8000 in browser

```
DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     2.0.2
Exception Type:     DisallowedHost
Exception Value:    

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Before you yell at me and tell that you should add the it in your ALLOWED_HOSTS fields in settings.py, I already did that as indicated [Why is Django throwing error "DisallowedHost at /"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667519/why-is-django-throwing-error-disallowedhost-at/40667600).

`Settings.py` field (I know if I put * then else everything is redundant, but still it gives me the same error.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*','0.0.0.0','127.0.0.1']
```

This is my wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wordtutor.settings")
# Uncommenting following also does not solve the error
#os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] =  "wordtutor.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

How can I solve this?

Edit : 
Python3.6
Django 2

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right `settings.py`? Try adding an error there and see if it's executed.

Comment: Yes, I am editing the same file. I get such an error too if i add anything random.  line 29, in <module>
    cdsjk
NameError: name 'cdsjk' is not defined

Comment: Try printing the value of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` at the end. Try removing middleware and apps one by one. Make sure there is no other settings file in the stack trace you for the error.

Comment: Ah..! Had another allowed_hosts below. how dumb of me. Thanks anyways.